# Inequality with the sides of a triangle.

Tags: inequality, holder-inequality, triangle-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ the sides of a triangle such that $a+b+c= \dfrac{1}{34^4}$. Show that:
$$ \sqrt[5]{a+b-c} + 16\sqrt[5]{a+c-b} + \sqrt[5]{b+c-a} \leq 1$$

I put $a = x+y, b=y+z$ and $c=z+x$ with $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^3$.
So I have to prove that $$ \sqrt[5]{2y} + 16\sqrt[5]{2x} + \sqrt[5]{2z} \leq 1 $$ and I think that I should maybe use minkowsky inequality but I can't make it in a good way.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome. Why did you put $a=x+y-z,...$? Where did the idea come from? I find $a+b-c=3y-x-z$?!

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, I wanted to use Ravi substitution, I edit

Answer (score 1):

By Holder(https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/holder-inequality/info) we obtain:
$$\sqrt[5]{a+b-c}+16\sqrt[5]{a+c-b}+\sqrt[5]{b+c-a}\leq$$
$$\leq\sqrt[5]{\left(1+32+1\right)^4(a+b-c+a+c-b+b+c-a)}=1.$$